# PHP search in array and if exists increment, else exit and return value

Tags: php, arrays

I have this type of array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 001
    [1] => 002
    [2] => 003
    [3] => 222
    [4] => 0002
    [5] => 0003
    [6] => 0004
    [7] => 1000
    [8] => 2000
    [9] => 3000
)
```

And I need to check if a value, "created" on the fly by code itself, exists or not. If not, use it, else increments it of 1 and check again (*for several reasons, I cannot pick the biggest number and simply add "1"*).

So, I did write this snippet, but I think that it never will exit from cycle and I don't know how re-check again (and again)...

```
$base_test = 001;
while (array_key_exists($base_test, $array_start))
{
     $base_test++;
     // how can I now re-check for this new value?
}
```

Comment: It will stop running once the key `$base_test` does not exist anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [recursive function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) like the following

```
function checkArray($val){
    $arr = array
    (
        0 => 001,
        1 => 002,
        2 => 003,
        3 => 222,
        4 => 0002,
        5 => 0003,
        6 => 0004,
        7 => 1000,
        8 => 2000,
        9 => 3000,
    );

    if(in_array($val ,$arr )){
      $val++;
      checkArray($val);
    }
      return $val;
}

echo checkArray(222);
```

Comment: I did try your code. Unfortunately seems that make the cycle only one time. If first $val passed exists, it returns $val+1 and stop, but in my case also the $val+1 exists, so it need to return a " $val+2" (i hope that you understand). Thank you

Comment: Just solved in this mode: function checkArray($value,$array)
{
 if (in_array($value,$array))
 {
  $value = $value+1;
  checkArray($value,$array);
 }
 else
 {
  echo $value; 
 }
}   Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:
It will check updated value for an array. 
Demo : https://eval.in/86549

```
<?php 
$arr = array
(
    "0" =>  "001",
     "1" =>  "002",
     "2" =>  "003",
     "3" =>  "222",
     "4" =>  "0002",
     "5" =>  "0003",
     "6" =>  "0004",
     "7" =>  "1000",
     "8" =>  "2000",
     "9" =>  "3000"
);
//get first count
$c = count($arr);

array_push($arr,"40000");
array_push($arr,"400001");
//get latest count after pushing data
$lc = count($arr);
echo "updated value: ";
while($c <= $lc){
    if(array_key_exists($c,$arr)){
        echo $arr[$c]." ";
    }
    $c = $c+1;
 }
```